# Pass descendant object as command parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

So i am creating a WPF application using the MVVM architectural pattern. Inside this application i have a listview. I have binded the SizeChanged event of the window to a command using this piece of XAML code:

```
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SizeChanged">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding WindowSizeChangedCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
```

Now, what i want is to pass to this command a parameter, which is the listview width.

I tried to do this by the following code

```
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SizeChanged">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding WindowSizeChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Width, ElementName=listView}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
```

The thing is that it doesn't work ! LOL I know how to find an ancestor object with XAML. But i don't know how to do the opposite. Any ideas what to do ?? Thank you very much for your time !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `Width` and not `ActualWidth` property for Binding

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding WindowSizeChangedCommand}" 
         CommandParameter="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=listView}" />
```

I assume that your command is already working and that is placed inside the following tag:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    ....
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

**P.S.**: 
Not sure what you are trying to do with the `Width` in the `ViewModel` but it is mostly not a good idea to deal with GUI-related things (like Width) there.